# Find the missing angle of a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

In this problem, there are three points on the surface of a unit sphere. Together with the center point of the sphere, the four points form a tetrahedron (barring cases where the four points are coplanar).

The volume of the tetrahedron is given, as are two of the three angles between arms of the tetrahedron (where apex is the center).

I have a clunky solution but it uses the quadratic equation which has more than one solution.

$$
0=1+2\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma  -\cos^2\alpha - \cos^2\beta - \cos^2\gamma -36V^2
$$

That's based on a formula from Wikipedia's ["Tetrahedron" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Volume) (setting $a=b=c=1$ because unit sphere).

Is there a better way? I was hoping to do it without the quadratic equation.

Comment: Consider, say, $\alpha=\beta=90^\circ$, so that the tetrahedron is essentially determined by two isosceles right triangles hinged along a common leg; and suppose $V$ is *nearly* zero. You can achieve that volume by having the hinge almost-completely *closed* (with the third face-angle $\gamma$ being almost-$0^\circ$), or almost-completely *open* (with $\gamma$ being almost-$180^\circ$). You can't simplify your problem beyond the quadratic because, in general, there can be two solutions.

Comment: It's worth noting that the solution to the quadratic can be written in the form 
$$\cos\gamma = \cos\alpha\cos\beta\pm\sqrt{\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta-36V^2}$$ which isn't too terrible.

Comment: You may want to convert your problem into vectors, and use scalar triple product and vector triple products.

Comment: @Blue that is a great insight and I wish I could mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comments to an answer:

Consider, say, $\alpha=\beta=90^\circ$, so that the tetrahedron is essentially determined by two isosceles right triangles hinged along a common leg; and suppose $V$ is *nearly* zero. You can achieve that volume by having the hinge almost-completely *closed* (with the third face-angle $\gamma$ being almost-$0^\circ$), or almost-completely *open* (with $\gamma$ being almost-$180^\circ$).

You can't simplify your problem beyond the quadratic because, in general, there can be two solutions.

---

It's worth noting that the solution to the quadratic can be written in the form
$$\cos\gamma = \cos\alpha\cos\beta\pm \sqrt{\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta-36V^2}$$
which isn't too terrible.

Note also that the discriminant factors as
$$(\sin\alpha\sin\beta+6V)\,(\sin\alpha\sin\beta-6V)$$
Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are presumably between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$, their sines are non-negative, and so also is the first factor above. Therefore, the sign of the discriminant (which tells us the nature of the roots) is determined by the second factor alone.

---

And yet another note ...

The dihedral angle (say, $\Gamma$) opposite face-angle $\gamma$ (ie, the "hinge angle" in the example above) satisfies
$$\cos \Gamma = \frac{\cos\gamma-\cos\alpha\cos\beta}{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}$$
(This is one of spherical geometry's [Laws of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines), but don't let the "spherical geometry" stuff intimidate you. In this context, the Laws simply relate the face-angles and dihedral angles at a vertex of a tetrahedron.)

Thus, we have
$$\cos\Gamma =\pm \sqrt{1-\frac{36V^2}{\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta}} \qquad\to\qquad \sin\Gamma = \frac{6V}{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}$$
(Presumably, $\Gamma$ is between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$, so I don't need a $\pm$ in the sine relation.) Although the equation is no longer expressly quadratic, it admits supplementary solutions. Eg, in the example above with $V\approx 0$, we have here $\sin\Gamma\approx0$, so that $\Gamma\approx0^\circ$ or $\Gamma\approx180^\circ$.